# Filtering Array of Objects having 2 of its items as reference in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

Good Day Developers,i have this 2 arrays

```
let arrayOfBookings=[
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "10:00_am"},
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "11:00_am"},
 {restaurantId: 2, turnName: "11:00_am"}
];

let restaurantSelectedTurns=[
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "10:00_am"},
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "11:00_am"},
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "12:00_am"},
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "01:00_pm"}
];
```

An having in mind the items of every object (restaurantId and turnName) where in if first of all
the restaurantId of both elements in comparison are equal then would be able to check if the turnName is not.
If that is the case , then i would push that object to a new array container.
Thus having in mind that logic i set this

```
...some variable called noRepeated:[]=[];

restaurantSelectedTurns.forEach((turn) => {
            arrayOfBookings.forEach((booking) => {
              if (turn.restaurantId == booking.restaurantId) {
                if (turn.turnName != booking.turnName) {
                  this.noRepeated.push(turn);
                }
              }
             

            });
            console.log(this.noRepeated);
          });
```

But for any reason when i log the not repeated result i got this

```
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "10:00_am"},
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "11:00_am"},
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "12:00_am"},
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "12:00_am"},
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "01:00_pm"},
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "01:00_pm"},
```

instead of

```
{restaurantId: 1, turnName: "12:00_am"},
 {restaurantId: 1, turnName: "01:00_pm"},
```

This logic is using angular .
Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. the first mistake you have in your code is that you iterate the
   array that contains more items.
2. the second is that you don't need to
   iterate the 2 tables and make a condition inside it, considered not
   solution for good performance.

So i try to make a simple solution for you:

```
const newArrayOfRestaurants = [];
for (const item of arrayOfBookings) {
    if (restaurantSelectedTurns.some(elt => elt.restaurantId === item.restaurantId && elt.turnName === item.turnName)){
        newArrayOfRestaurants.push(item);
    }
}
```